# Supplying Power to an ExpressCard USB 3.0 Adapter

Tags: usb, power, expresscard

I have a ExpressCard USB 3 adapter for my MacBook Pro 17.  It is working fine, but it does not seem to be able to properly power my external HDD.   The card has a power barrel connection on it, but I don't know what the power specifications are or what adapter I would need.

I see on the site that the unit usually comes with a "DC to USB Adapter Cable", but I did not get one with mine.  Would a card like this directly deliver the power from the barrel connector to the USB port?  Should I just be able to use standard 5v USB power by plugging into another one of my USB ports and converting to the right size of barrel connector?

The card I am using is a [1 Port Flush Mount ExpressCard SuperSpeed USB 3.0 Card Adapter with UASP Support](https://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/USB-3.0/Cards/1-Port-Flush-Mount-ExpressCard-SuperSpeed-USB-3-Card-Adapter~ECUSB3S11).

Comment: Whoever it was that voted to close this question: I don't know your reasoning, but I reworked my question to try and make it better.  A comment as to why you don't like it would be nice...

Comment: The barrel connector on your card is to supply full power to the adapter's USB 3.0 port. Yes, you can use either a USB-to-DC plug cable (which is missing from your package) from any other USB port, or use an external AC-DC power adapter with matching barrel plug (likely something like 1.3mm/3mm plug). This question is about "use of equipment", so it should be closed as "off-topic".

Comment: @Ale..chenski, Thanks for the comment.  I would classify this as a hardware question as mentioned in the FAQ.  That being said, I do not see how a question about the usage of a computer hardware component would be off topic on Super User.  I had to go read the FAQ again just to double check, and I don't see what your concern is.  Is there a specific SE site that you think would be a better fit on?